# GroupBy is being shown as a singular line on plot

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, pandas-groupby

I'm trying to create a plot to show profit over time through a pandas dataframe. Here are the steps I have taken:

```py
profit_data=agg_data.groupby(['segment','yyyy_mm_dd'])[["profit"]].sum()
profit_data
```

This gives me a dataframe similar to the below:

```
                        profit
segment    yyyy_mm_dd   
Core       2019-06-01   100
           2019-06-02   100
           2019-06-03   100
           2019-06-04   100
           2019-06-05   100
NonCore    2019-06-07   100
           2019-06-08   100
           2019-06-09   100
           2019-06-10   100
...
...
```

I then try to plot this using `matplotlib`:

```
profit_data.plot()
```

The above does generate a plot, however my segments are one continuous line rather than two different lines (one for each segment). What change do I need to make so each segment is plotted?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your output dataframe is only one column, so only one column gets plotted.

To solve this, you need to reshape your dataframe into two columns - one for each segment:

```py
df_unstacked = df.unstack(level="segment")
```

Alternatively, you could select which indices to plot and plot twice:

```py
df.loc["Core"].plot(label="Core")
df.loc["NonCore"].plot(label="NonCore")
```

Hope this helps!